# php preg_split and UTF-8 symbols

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-split

Could anybody explain, why this code

```
$string='6аd_ТЕХТ GOOD_TEXT';
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

var_dump($words);
```

displays

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "6àd_ÒÅÕÒ" [1]=> string(9) "GOOD_TEXT" }
```

instead of

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "6аd_ТЕХТ" [1]=> string(9) "GOOD_TEXT" }
```

I've read about this issue, but adding /u :

```
preg_split('/\s+/', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);// '/\s+/'
```

to become

```
preg_split('/\s+/u', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);// '/\s+/u'
```

doesn't help.
How to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: ASCII-safe string cannot become what you shown using just `preg_split` http://ideone.com/pH45p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something else happening in your code that isn't present in the provided example. Tested the provided example and it works as expected. On the off-chance that this *is* really happening (and there is no other code affecting `$string`), this may be a bug with the specific PHP version you're using and can be solved by upgrading PHP (but it's highly unlikely that it's an issue with PHP).

Answer (score 0):

... I said it was the slash, but apparently it was the utf-8 stuff that made it work.

EDIT: I removed the rest and found that all I needed was the xml line to make it work in the browser.

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?'.'>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head><body><pre>
';

$string = "6аd_ТЕХТ GOOD_TEXT";
var_dump(preg_split('/\s+/u', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

echo '</pre></body></html>';
```

This is the output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "6аd_ТЕХТ"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "GOOD_TEXT"
}
```

Comment: As some background, PHP requires backslashes within `preg_` functions to be escaped. So, if you want to escape something with `\`, you need to use `\\`. If you want to use a literal backslash, you must use `\\\\`. Huge pain, but it works.

Comment: @bfrohs you are correct. I didn't even test it with one slash. Took it out and worked just fine. I guess just needed utf8 stuff to tell php what to do.

Comment: @bfrohs actually, I started removing stuff, and found that it was the xml tag that did it. php handled the rest fine.

Comment: yeah, it tends to work fine, but it's a good habit to get into to avoid issues down the road :)